# Wordpress In Menu

Tags: plugins

I am using woocommerce plugin in my WordPress setup. I want the Checkout in the menu bar should appear only when there is something in the cart. How can I do this?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the OP would like to show a Checkout menu item when there is something in the cart. @Rekha Haridoss could you confirm? The question and especially title should be edited if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust what items are shown in the menu via the `wp_get_nav_menu_items`. This is the same filter that I am using in my Nav Menu Roles plugin.  Adapting from that, we can loop through the menu items, and check if any of them are links to the "checkout" page. From there we can test if the cart is empty.  If both are true, then we remove the item from the menu.

```
function wpa_120740_exclude_menu_items( $items ){  //var_dump( $items );
    global $woocommerce;

    if( is_admin() || ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_get_page_id' ) ) return $items;

      // Iterate over the items to search and destroy
      foreach ( $items as $key => $item ) {  

          if( $item->object_id == woocommerce_get_page_id( 'checkout' ) ){
            $cart_contents = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
            if( empty ( $cart_contents ) ){
                 unset( $items[$key] ) ;
            }
          }
      }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'wpa_120740_exclude_menu_items' );
```